ITextPDFHTML converterProperties.setCreateAcroForm(true) getting a blank page in java
I am trying to convert HTML that contains text input elements to PDF using ITextPDF including Page numbers in the Footer of each page. I am using the following dependency
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

I am using the "pdfhtmlheaderandfooter" Example from the itextpdf KB.
However this does not render the Input elements in my example HTML
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <form>
    <fieldset>Hello: 
        <input type="text" name="place" value="world">
        <br>This is:
        <input type="text" name="who" value="me">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

So I change this section
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(SRC);
HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdfDocument, converterProperties);

to
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(SRC);
converterProperties.setCreateAcroForm(true);
HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdfDocument, converterProperties);

But now the entire Page is blank.
If I switch to
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdfDocument, converterProperties);

instead of
HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), pdfDocument, converterProperties);

results in a correctly fillable PDF beeing created, but missing the Total Page number, as I also have to comment out
footerHandler.writeTotal(pdfDocument);

as this will throw a nullpointer when using convertToPdf.
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some setting?
